# What is a DNS namespace?

Tags: domain-name-system

What is a DNS namespace? Ie if someone asks me if I own "the DNS namespace". I haven't been able to find a basic definition yet.

Comment: What did you want to do when you got asked that question?

Comment: Register records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the domain name you own. For example `domainname.com`. Also you can own a third level domain namespace for example `subdomain.domain.net`.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! So for a public hostname, it's ending in .com or something similar.

Comment: Your public hostname (aka FQDN - Fully Qualified Domain Name) can be a part of a domain so it would be the leftmost part (ex. `webserver.example.org`) which is a member of `example.org` domain. This part (webserver) is stored as a resource record on a DNS server.

Comment: Yep, got it. For a public hostname for apps which require it such as vpn servers, must it be a valid domain name (i.e. ending in .com) or a hostname of the server where the AD domain suffix may end in .local?

Comment: If you want to be accessed from public you have to have a registered domain, it doesn't matter if it's `.com`, but there's definitely no top-level domain `.local` in public. Though all your intranet users could be able to access that as long as they used your own DNS server